# Is it possible to create an object using the value in a TextBox?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with two text boxes. The TexBox should always look empty. When a user types a value in. The typed value is added to a value which already exists in a table field. Is this even possible? The table has two coloumns currentValue and finalValue.

```
Private sub currentValue_AfterUpdate()
Dim enterValue As Long
Dim finalValue As Long

enterValue = New TextBox Object
finalValue = value + Me.Recordset("currentValue")
Update finalValue_AfterUpdate
Me.enterValue.Visible = Fales

End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the Field (from your Table) to a Form Textbox (txt1)

Hide this control.

Add an unbound Textbox (txt2) to the Form which is for the user to add their value.
Like your idea have an after update event.

```
Private Sub txt2_AfterUpdate()
    txt1 = txt1 + txt2
End Sub
```

Example code, untested.

The record is then dirty so it will need saving but you can handle that how you wish